# Run Timer Job on a specific Web Application

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, scope, feature-scope

I have a custom timer job in which the scope of the timer job is "Web Application", which is defined in feature of timer job.

Now When i have deployed the timer-job it runs for all the web application in the farm. Is there a way where we can define the scope of this timer-job to a specific web Application .

Comment: You can deactivate custom timer job web application feature in your web application. Deploy your solution on particular web application only in the farm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your scope of timer job is already at `Web Application`.

So what you have to do is, just make sure the feature should not be auto activated. You just disable the setting `Automatically Activate`.

So, just activate the feature on the `Web Application` you need to use.

Answer (score 7):

A job does not have a thing such as a "scope". They have a lock (`Job`, `Database` and `None`) but that's something else.
So you're actually talking about the *scope of the feature* that deploys (through a feature event receiver).
Several things have to be noted:

- Web application-scoped features are (by default) automatically activated when the WSP is deployed. That means your feature is activated multiple times, once per content Web application you have in the farm.
- This means multiple instances of your job may be created (e.g. 2 Web applications -> 2 jobs are created in the list of job definitions).
- It's up to you to associate the Web application the feature is activated on to the job you're instantiating. This can be done by setting the `WebApplication` property of the job:

`public MyJobDefinition(SPWebApplication webApp) :
        base(GetJobName(webApp), webApp, null, SPJobLockType.Job) { }`

- Then, in the `Execute` method, you may access the Web app and enumerate (for instance) its site collections to get the job done on each.
- You may give a name to your job that reflects the Web app it's associated with.
- You can deactivate the feature on the Web applications you don't want it: don't forget that add code in the feature ER when the feature deactivates to unregister the job for that Web app.

A good sample can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx.